# 16-bit entry in a S-Box of a SPN block cipher: Would it have the same speed/performance than a 8-bit entry?

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes, spn

I learned that in [Substitution–permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution%E2%80%93permutation_network) block ciphers, the maximum size of S-Box set to receive an entry from a data is the max numeric count of the data, for example, if the entry is 8-bits the S-Box set to be used is 256-bytes as 2^8=256.

Would 16-bits entries in a S-Box set of 65536-bytes (2^16) deliver the same speed/performance (cycles per byte) to the cipher as well as if was used 8-bits entries in a 256-byte S-Box set?

16-bits entries require a larger S-Box set (65536 bytes), would it be 256 times slower that if it was used a 8-bits entry? (as 65536/256=256).

Comment: Speed is generally dependent on implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly note that a $2^{16}$-long look up table of 16-bit=2-byte entries takes up 131,072 bytes of space.

Your question is very architecture dependent. For speedy encryption you would want the S-loaded into the fastest bit of memory cache (L1 cache is a frequently used term). Now the Pentium III for example had [32KB of L1 cache](https://www.computerworld.com/article/2595301/cache-memory.html) which could easily cope with a 256B S-box, but would not be able to cope with your S-Box. It would be swapping sections of the table in and out and taking a performance hit. More modern processors such as the Xeon series have [1-2MB of L1 cache](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/what-is-cpu-cache/) and might be able to cope. If you want to encrypt stuff in resource constrained environments such as mobile phones and and IoT sensors (and this is the focus of a great deal of block cipher design these days), note that for example the [ARM Cortex A L1 cache is typically 32 kB or 64 kB](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/100048/0002/level-1-memory-system/about-the-l1-memory-system) and would not cope well.

The overall effect is probably much less than a factor of 256 (but again architecture dependent bus speeds will affect this). However the variation in time produced by cache swapping increases the danger of timing side channel attacks ([Bernstein "Cache timing attacks on AES"](https://cr.yp.to/antiforgery/cachetiming-20050414.pdf) showed that cache timing effects can cause vulnerabilities in AES implementations). This now becomes a question not just of performance degradation but also security degradation.